# TabLayout still crahsing

Tags: android

I made a ViewPager/TabLayout app like in this video (everything same, but I don't have AppBarLayout and ImageView): [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zaKUc2zfpI)

But if I want to try the app the debugger says:  "*Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerExceptio*n" at line 24

Here's some Code:

MainActivity.java (where the problem is)

```
TabLayout tablayout;
ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentElso(), "Elso");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentMasodik(), "Masodik");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentHarmadik(), "Harmadik");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tablayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager); *(line 24)*
}
```

}

Fragments(here's one, but all 3 are exactly the same)

```
View viewelso;
public FragmentElso() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    viewelso = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elso, container, false);
    return viewelso;
}
```

}
And here's the ViewPagerAdapter

```
public final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
public final List<String> FragmentListTitles = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return FragmentListTitles.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return FragmentListTitles.get(position);
}
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String Title){
    fragmentList.add(fragment);
    FragmentListTitles.add(Title); 
}
```

}

And I have everywhere the import: *android.support.v4.app.Fragment;*

In advance thanks for every help!

Comment: `tablayout` is null, simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't initialized your TableLayout, so it's is null. Take a look at 19:21 of the video.